# How can I fix the error when using the Sharp library?

Tags: node.js, express, multer, sharp

I want to resize and compress images using sharp library in node.js. The code was taken from this [article](https://dev.to/franciscomendes10866/image-compression-with-node-js-4d7h), but for some reason returns an error.

**Error**

```
PS D:\Code\Web\image-compressor-nodejs> node index.js
[Error: ./uploads/2022-08-10T18:35:49.251Z-2021-11-18_23.44.45.png.webp: unable to open for write
windows error: ���������� �� �������� �������.

]
```

**Code**

```
const express = require("express");
const multer = require("multer");
const sharp = require("sharp");
const fs = require("fs");

const app = express();
const storage = multer.memoryStorage();
const upload = multer({ storage });

app.use(express.static("./uploads"));

app.post("/", upload.single("picture"), async (req, res) => {
  try {
    fs.access("./uploads", (error) => {
      if (error) {
        fs.mkdirSync("./uploads");
      }
    });
    const { buffer, originalname } = req.file;
    const timestamp = new Date().toISOString();
    const ref = `${timestamp}-${originalname}.webp`;
    await sharp(buffer)
      .webp({ quality: 20 })
      .toFile("./uploads/" + ref);
    const link = `http://localhost:3000/${ref}`;
    return res.json({ link });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
});

app.listen(3000);
```

Answer (score 1):

The error message is rather inconclusive. The problem is that the timestamp consists of characters that are not valid on Windows systems but on a Linux-based system it should work fine.

Try the following instead:

```js
const timestamp = new Date()
      .toISOString()
      .replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9_\\-]/g, "-");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
const express = require("express");
const multer = require("multer");
const sharp = require("sharp");
const fs = require("fs");

const app = express();
const storage = multer.memoryStorage();
const upload = multer({ storage });

app.use(express.static("./uploads"));

app.post("/", upload.single("picture"), async (req, res) => {
  try {
    if (!fs.existsSync("./uploads")) { // check if directory exists. Do so synchronously.
      fs.mkdirSync("./uploads");
    }
    const { buffer, originalname } = req.file;
    const timestamp = new Date().toISOString();
    const ref = `${timestamp}-${originalname}.webp`;
    await sharp(buffer)
      .webp({ quality: 20 })
      .toFile("./uploads/" + ref);
    const link = `http://localhost:3000/${ref}`;
    return res.json({ link });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
});

app.listen(3000);
```

You need to check to see if the `./uploads` directory exists in a synchronous manner. `fs.access` in your original code is asynchronous.